# DocuSign JWT Authentication: Unexpected PEM type

Tags: c#, oauth, jwt, docusignapi

I can't authenticate with DocuSign's OAuth JWT because of the error `Unexpected PEM Type`. I'm using their Nuget package 2.2.0. If I change to 2.1.10 and tweak my code slightly I get this error

```
Error calling Login: {
    "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
    "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}
```

I only have a Sandbox account, which I have created an Integrator Key. My redirect uri is `https://docusign.com` and I created an RSA Keypair which I saved the private key in a PEM file.

I'm following the instructions here https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/README.md but an exception is raised on the line `OAuth.OAuthToken tokenInfo = apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey(integratorKey, userId, oauthBasePath, privateKey, expiresInHours);`

I have also granted access to JWT using the url `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=<integrator-key>&redirect_uri=https://docusign.com`.

```
string userId = "e1f43c1a-2546-4317-85a9-cea367f8f92c";
string oauthBasePath = "account-d.docusign.net";
string integratorKey = "<integrator-key>";
string privateKey = @"C:\Users\me\privateKey.pem";
int expiresInHours = 1;
string host = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason sticking the `userId`, `oauthBasePath`, `integratorKey`, `privateKey`, `expiresInHours` and `host` all in a new class worked.

I also had to pass the contents of the PEM file instead of the file path.

```
 public class FooConfig
{
    public string Host { get; set; }

    public string IntegratorKey { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string OAuthBasePath { get; set; }

    public string PrivateKeyFilename { get; set; }

    public int ExpiresInHours { get; set; }

    public ApiClient ApiClient { get; set; }

    public FooConfig()
    {
        this.UserId = "e1f43c1a-2546-4317-85a9-cea367f8f92c";
        this.OAuthBasePath = "account-d.docusign.com";
        this.IntegratorKey = "<integrator-key>";
        this.PrivateKeyFilename = @"C:\Users\me\privateKey.pem";
        this.ExpiresInHours = 1;
        this.Host = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";
    }
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

FooConfig testConfig = new FooConfig();
testConfig.ApiClient = new ApiClient(testConfig.Host);

// If this is the first time logging in - Get Consent from the user - this is a onetime step.
Uri oauthURI = testConfig.ApiClient.GetAuthorizationUri(testConfig.IntegratorKey, scopes, "https://docusign.com", OAuth.CODE, "testState");
Process.Start(oauthURI.ToString());

string key = File.ReadAllText(testConfig.PrivateKeyFilename);
OAuth.OAuthToken tokenInfo = testConfig.ApiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey(testConfig.IntegratorKey, testConfig.UserId, testConfig.OAuthBasePath, key, testConfig.ExpiresInHours);
```

Comment: Note that the URL in the `AuthorizationUri` needs to match your redirect url in your integrator key

Comment: +1 for GetAuthUri - didn't realize I'd need something like that and that was useful. The solution to my problem was solved with FileReadAllText instead of Encoding.Ascii/UTF/etc.GetBytes().

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this message with the most current version, using this method signature:

```
RequestJWTUserToken(_config.ClientId, _config.UserId, $"account-d.docusign.com", _config.Key, 1);
```

I had copy/pasted the contents of the .pem file from the website. Opening the .pem in Notepad++ and switching its encoding from UTF-8 BOM to just UTF-8 resolved this error for me.

Comment: That was fix I needed. I copied from the website and pasted into a new text file I created with Visual Studio which I guess was not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and resolved it by using the following code below. It seems that in the previous SDK ( <=2.1.10 ?) required the physical file location, now (SDK >= 2.2.0 ?), the file content is required

```
testConfig.PrivateKeyFilename = File.ReadAllText("./private.pem");

OAuth.OAuthToken tokenInfo = apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey
            (testConfig.IntegratorKey, testConfig.UserId, testConfig.OAuthBasePath, testConfig.PrivateKeyFilename, testConfig.ExpiresInHours);
```

Comment: At least now in the api its ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow - takes filename and ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey uses the key data itself

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, it depends the version of the API you're using

Comment: Actually, in the 2.2.1 DocuSign C# SDK, the method is marked as deprecated and it is advised to use the ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey method instead

Comment: Yes, after upgrading, I have start using the new call.  Where you send the key via byte[] or Stream instead of string

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but maybe it helps someone:

I tried anything without success, then I ended up noticing that the issue was on the "**BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll**" version.
It seems that I had an older version in my project.

**Installing the latest one** (1.9.0) solved my issue